# get by latitude and longitude in laravel 5 with other joins

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, latitude-longitude

This is quite a complicated one for me. I have a route that is a search - which works quite well, except I am unable to search by postcode to find the nearest to the lat and long of a given postcode. That is, I can work out the lat and long, but I am not sure how to integrate it to my existing query. This query is the search query without postcodes:

```
$query = DB::table('dogs');
$query->leftJoin('dog_addresses','dogs.id','=','dog_addresses.dog_id');
$query->leftJoin('dog_videos','dogs.id','=','dogs_videos.dog_id');
$query->leftJoin('dogs_breeds','dogs.breed_id','=','dogs_breeds.id');
if($request->input("breed") && $request->input("breed") != "" && $request->input("breed") != "any")
    {
        $breed = Dog_Breed::where("breed_name", $request->input("breed"))->first();
        $query->where('dogs.breed_id', $breed->id);
    }
$results = $query->get();
```

I have something to add to the query to get the latitude and longitude of the postcode:

```
if($request->input("postcode")) 
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" . $request->input('postcode'));
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
    $postcode_lat = $result->result->latitude;
    $postcode_long = $result->result->longitude;            
}
```

This lets me get my postcode latitute and longitude.
But I don't then know how to get the dogs by location based on the lat and long columns present in the dog_addresses table, which is joined to the dogs table. How do I do this?

So if my dog_addresses table has the columns Lat and Long.

So dogs:

```
id | user_id | dog_name | age
```

dog_addresses:

```
id | dog_id | address_line_1 | town | postcode | lat | long
```

So for my query I need to get all dogs, where bred ID is 1, but I want to inner join videos so I can get all video information and addresses information, but I also want to sort the order of dogs returned by how close they are to my inputted postcode, based on lat and long.

I'm very confused. I found this:

```
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
```

But I'm still not sure how to integrate it, or what use it is for me.
Please help

Comment: check my answer, if it works for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code would be able to retrieve the results in the way you wanted. Code explanation in-line.

```
if($request->input("postcode")) 
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" . $request->input('postcode'));
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
    $postcode_lat = $result->result->latitude;
    $postcode_long = $result->result->longitude;   

    $query = DB::table('dogs');
    //Join statement responsible for retrieving dogs addresses based on latitude and longitude in address table.
    $query->join(DB::raw('(SELECT  dog_id, (
                              3959 * acos (
                              cos ( radians($postcode_lat) )
                              * cos( radians( lat ) )
                              * cos( radians( long ) - radians($postcode_long) )
                              + sin ( radians($postcode_lat) )
                              * sin( radians( lat ) )
                            )       
                    )AS distance from dog_addresses) as dog_addresses'), function ($join){
            $join->on('dogs.id', '=', 'dog_addresses.dog_id')

        }); 
    $query->leftJoin('dog_videos','dogs.id','=','dogs_videos.dog_id');
    $query->leftJoin('dogs_breeds','dogs.breed_id','=','dogs_breeds.id');
    if($request->input("breed") && $request->input("breed") != "" && $request->input("breed") != "any")
    {
        $breed = Dog_Breed::where("breed_name", $request->input("breed"))->first();
        $query->where('dogs.breed_id', $breed->id);
    }
    $results = $query->orderBy('dog_addresses.distance', 'ASC') //Ordering the results in ascending order by calculated distance 
                    ->limit(20) //Limiting the results to 20 . Can be changed or removed according to your needs
                    ->get(); //Retrieving the results
}
```

Comment: Actually I get the following error with this: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::Select() - It seems it doesn't like ->Select added to the $join->on. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidG will check one and let you know in 30mins

Comment: I get this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dog_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select * from `dogs` inner join (SELECT dog_id, (
3959 * acos (
cos ( radians(50.721503042443) )
* cos( radians( `lat` ) )
* cos( radians( `long` ) - radians(-1.8740252546828) )
+ sin ( radians(50.721503042443) )
* sin( radians( `lat` ) )
) 
) AS distance) dog_addresses on `dogs`.`id` = `dog_addresses`.`dog_id`

Comment: Hi @DavidG, sorry for these errors.. I'm looking into it just 15 mins, I just got home will try the solution on my laravel setup

Comment: Thank you :) Sorry to be a pest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120986/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-david-g).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your latest edit did the trick! I appreciate that you came back to help out days later with the edits, really awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can try the GLength function of mysql:

```
SELECT 
    *,  GLength(LineString(GeomFromText('POINT(latPosCode,lngPosCode)'),GeomFromText('POINT(latInDataBase,lngInDataBase)'),)) AS DISTANCE
FROM dogs           
ORDER BY DISTANCE
```

Comment: But how would I then join the other tables? If you don't mind me asking