# PHP latitude and longitude radius

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, maps, latitude-longitude

I make a service that give the nearby location of driver to passenger.

Is this query working? Is it actually search nearby location radius of passenger?

I just put the latitude and longitude a number.

Can you guys verify or explain to me?

```
SELECT  b.id, b.name, b.latitude, b.longitude
FROM    passenger a
JOIN    driver b
ON      ACOS(COS(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.longitude) - RADIANS(a.longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude))) <= 10 / 6371.0
WHERE   a.latitude = 3.2046532 AND a.longitude = 101.7808791
```

---

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
include ("conn.php");

$latitude1 = 3.2046532;
$longitude1 = 101.7808791;

$stmt = $dbi->prepare("SELECT b.id, b.name, b.latitude, b.longitude
                FROM passenger a
                JOIN driver b
                ON ACOS(COS(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.longitude) - RADIANS(a.longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude))) <= 10 / 6371.0
                WHERE   a.latitude = ? AND a.longitude = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $latitude1,$longitude1); 
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
$stmt->bind_result($newID, $newName, $latitude2, $longitude2);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

echo $newName.'<br>';
echo $latitude2.'<br>';
echo $longitude2.'<br>';

?>
```

Comment: You have to verify your codes yourself, we can mostly help if you get into any error

Comment: That's what it looks like.  But I'd have to run it to be sure.  Gimme a minute.

Comment: @jaysingkar i code in php wait a minute i post the code

Comment: @jaysingkar already post. Take a look

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: @manetsus okay. my problem is, in this query it is exactly find the nearby location of driver that passenger requested. so i want to know it is this query correct and actually working perfectly?

Comment: @manetsus As I understand, you are retrieving all the drivers along the 10 km distance from the user ?

Comment: if this is the case, your query is good, but I couldn't understand why you are using join

Comment: @jaysingkar yes correct.

Comment: could you please explain, why you are using join ? I don't think it is needed, and your distance won't be the key to be used in `on` clause.

Comment: @jaysingkar if not join. What it would be?

Comment: I will post a answer, check it.

Comment: @krxckz check the answer

Comment: @jaysingkar check my new query. it is working?

Comment: my query not working ?

Comment: I think your distance's formula is not correct. please recheck

Comment: @jaysingkar check my new query. i use another option from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919661/select-within-20-kilometers-based-on-latitude-longitude

Comment: @krxckz is there any problem in my query ?

Comment: @jaysingkar nothing show up. I dont know what error

Comment: @jaysingkar how to selected answer?

Comment: there would be a tick mark against my answer, where you upvote or downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sql query would look something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbi->prepare("SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude,
                (ACOS(COS(RADIANS(?)) * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.longitude) - RADIANS(?)) + SIN(RADIANS(?)) * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude)))) as distance 
                FROM driver
                WHERE   distance <= 10/6371.0");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $latitude1,$longitude1,$latitude1);
```

**Explanation:**
In the above query I'm calculating the distance of driver from the passenger as `distance` and then selecting those drivers who are in the 10 km area.
In `distance <= 10/6371` statement, `6371` is used as it is the value of radius of earth in kms. `3956` can be used in place of `6371` if you want to calculate the distance in miles, as `3956` is the earth's radius in miles.
More information regarding this can be found [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/mysql-calculating-distance-based-on-latitude-and-longitude.html).
If you want to retrieve the passengers details as well, use different query instead of join, as you must be having the passenger's primary key since he's the one requesting for driver's lists.

### Update:

```
$stmt = $dbi->prepare("SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude,
            6371 * (ACOS(COS(RADIANS(?)) * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.longitude) - RADIANS(?)) + SIN(RADIANS(?)) * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude)))) AS distance
            FROM     driver
            HAVING distance <= 10
            ORDER BY distance ASC");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $latitude1,$longitude1,$latitude1);
```

Comment: in bind result, you can also bind the distance so as to provide user with the info regarding how far each driver is

Comment: joins can be used in this scenario, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676500/get-by-latitude-and-longitude-in-laravel-5-with-other-joins/38801699#38801699