# passing parameters to a method in a query using whereRaw

Tags: php, laravel-5, where-clause

How can I pass parameters to a method in my query using whereRaw?

I've got 'syntax error, unexpected '.'' when trying to add 'latitude' and 'longitude' which are column names:

```
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) {
  $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)
                  ->whereRaw( 'radio + ' . $radio . ' <= ' . $this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon, . 'latitude, longitude)');
  return response()->json($results);
}
```

If I delete that dot, I end up passing 2 floats + 2 strings to my method instead the 4 floats required, so I get error 500.

```
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) 
{   
    $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)->whereRaw( 'radio + ' . $radio . ' <= ' . $this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon, 'latitude', 'longitude'));   
    return response()->json($results); 
}
```

Edit:

'radio', 'longitude' and 'latitude' are column names containing a float value.

```
public function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2) {
  $R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  $dLat = deg2rad($lat2-$lat1);
  $dLon = deg2rad($lon2-$lon1);
  $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2))
       + sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);
  $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
  $d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return $d;
}
```

Comment: getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2)

Comment: $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)->whereRaw( 'radio + ' . $radio . ' <= ' . $this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon, 'latitude', 'longitude'));

Comment: you are passing float and strings only..... `$lat, $lon` floats and ` 'latitude', 'longitude'` strings ?

Comment: I need to pass 4 floats. $lat1 and $lon1 is easy because are the variables that my Show method receive, but not sure how to pass $lat2 and $lon2 because they are all values in my column 'latitude' and 'longitude'.

Comment: can you post the table structure ?

Comment: you cannot use function inside query

Comment: what you can do is, put the calculations from the `getDistanceFromLatLonInKm` function in the query

Comment: post your function and I will let you know how to do that

Comment: I edited my post. It's a hard task to put all the calculations into the query.. I still have hopes of being able to call the method.

Comment: I think you can put that code in the query....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676500/get-by-latitude-and-longitude-in-laravel-5-with-other-joins/38801699#38801699

Comment: I have modified the query according to your needs... check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) 
{   
    $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)->selectRaw('*,(
                              6371 * acos (
                              cos ( radians($lat) )
                              * cos( radians( latitude ) )
                              * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lon) )
                              + sin ( radians($lat) )
                              * sin( radians( latitude ) )
                            )       
                    )AS distance')
                    ->whereRaw(radio + ' . $radio . ' <= distance')
                    ->get();
    return response()->json($results); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming radio is the table name in which this lattitude and longitude column are there if not so than replace radio with the table name in place of radio.longitude and radio.latitude to tablename.latitude and tablename.longitude

```
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) {
            $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)
            ->whereRaw( 'radio + ' . $radio . ' <= ' .$this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon,radio.latitude, radio.longitude));
return response()->json($results);
 }
```

Comment: I just edited my post saying that 'radio', 'longitude' and 'latitude' are column names. The table name is Viaje.

Comment: and Viaje.latitude doesn't work, gives me error 500.

Comment: what is radio and what value you are passing in $radio is suppose radio is column name  where you are applying where condition can you please add the related table schema over here so that i can write down query for it

Comment: Radio is also a float. For each register I have a value for radio, longitude and latitude. $lon, $lat and $radio are the variables for the user itself and want to compare these values with the whole table and retrieve the ones accomplishing that sentence.

Comment: can you please add a sample data of two to three rows and pass the values and show me what actually output you desired ? i mean a example because i am not able to get why you are doing 'radio +'.$radio  on in where clause left side argument is always a column but in your case both side you are passing computational values can you please write some more details

Comment: Imagine many points in a map, each one has latitude, longitude and a radio (in Km) creating a circle around it. I want to know which circles intersect, to do that, I calculate the distance between my location with the rest (getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($myLat, $myLon, $otherLat,$otherLon), and only when this value is higher than the sum of $myRadio and $otherRadio means that I got an intersection and I want back that register. But how to pass $otherLat and $otherLon in the method?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out and see what it produce the results
public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) {

```
$results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)->select('fields','radio + '. $radio .'as total_radio')
                ->whereRaw('total_radio <='. function($q) use ($lat,$lot,$this)  {
                    return $this->getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon,$q->select('lattitude'), $q->select('longitude'));
        });
return response()->json($results);
 }
```

Comment: Laravel doesn't allow me to put $this so I put $radio, I keep having the errorException: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string. I've tried to understand this error without success, any idea?

Comment: Remove the parameter $this from function and make this getDistanceFromLatLonInKm() function static  and than use it. It will resolve your issue

Comment: It doesn't work, same error :S And the weird thing is that it's pointing to the line where only I have: });

Comment: public function show($lon, $lat, $radio) { $results = Viaje::where($otherStuff)->select('fields','radio + '. $radio .'as total_radio')
                ->whereRaw('total_radio <='. function($q) use ($lat,$lot)  {
                    return getDistanceFromLatLonInKm($lat, $lon,$q->select('latitude'), $q->select('longitude'));
        });
return response()->json($results);
 }           errorException: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string